# Identifying most cited researchers in Scopus for specific discipline and country

Tags: scopus

I am planning to conduct a qualitative research study focusing on the 20 most cited Italian cardiovascular researchers in Scopus.

I have explored the dedicated search tools but cannot find any suitable means.

Is there a way (automated or via SQL, R, or Python query)?